# Different parameter name in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 kendo grid, I have passed like this in link column.

```
columns
    .Bound(m => m.TID )
    .ClientTemplate("<a href='" 
        + Url.Action("AddMerchant", "Merchant", new { MerchantId = 10 ,AddressId = 30}) 
        + "'>Edit</a>");
```

so i got like this

```
/Merchant/AddMerchant?MerchantId=10&AddressId=30
```

But I need

```
/Merchant/AddMerchant/10/30 .
```

but if I get I can't able to read parameter value in action named like `MerchantId` and `AddressId`

Comment: Please post your route table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by map custom routes to the `RouteConfig.cs` file for your controller and its action method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Merchant",
            url: "Merchant/AddMerchant/{MerchantId}/{AddressId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Merchant", action = "AddMerchant }
        );
```

Comment: I have tried like this . but not working.          **routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ADDMerchant",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{Merchantid}{AddressId}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Merchant", action = "AddMerchant", id = UrlParameter.Optional } **

Comment: try what I sent. And remember that you should put it before the `default` mapRoute

Comment: **Thank you so much**. it's working fine. before i added it at last position.